# Binomial-like distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, binomial-coefficients

Starting with $1$, for $n$ trials multiply by either $1+p$ or $1-p$, with $0 \le p< \le 1$. Does this distribution have a name? What are its properties, such as density (PDF)? It is like a skewed binomial distribution, since the outcomes for $2$ rounds for example are $1(1+p)^2,\ 2(1+p)(1-p), \ 1(1-p)^2$. The mean is $((1+p) + (1-p))^n / 2^n = 1$.

The distribution has some interesting behavior. For example, for $p = 1$, there is a one way to get $2^n$, but all others are $0$.

Comment: It cannot be a pdf, because $P(X=2)=(1+p)^2 >1$

Comment: @calculus Treat $1+p$ and $1-p$ as 50% chance of occuring

Comment: At the moment I have no idea.

Comment: The pdf should be $f(n|k)=0.5^n\ \forall \ k=1,2,3,\ldots ,n $. And the outcomes are ${n \choose k}\cdot (1+p)^k \cdot (1-p)^{n-k}$. Therefore the expected value is $\sum_{k=0}^n 0.5^n\cdot {n \choose k}\cdot (1+p)^k \cdot (1-p)^{n-k}=0.5^n\cdot \sum_{k=0}^n  {n \choose k}\cdot (1+p)^k \cdot (1-p)^{n-k}=0.5^n\cdot ((1+p)+(1-p))^n=0.5^n\cdot2^n=1 $